# Returning indices of variables in a three-dimensional matrix satisfying a condition

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find the value of 3 variables that satisfy a condition, namely that their sum is less than or equal to 1. My approach is to use `ndgrid` to sweep over all combinations of the variables and define a matrix `I` that contains a `1` if the condition is satisfied. My code is below

```
ss=0.25;
[pp1,pp2,pp3] = ndgrid(0:ss:1,0:ss:1,0:ss:1);
I = pp1+pp2+pp3<=1
```

My question is, how do I generate a list of all valid variable combinations? I wish to have a `3 x n` vector `p` that contains all `n` valid values for `pp1`,`pp2`, and `pp3`.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution which I'll post as an answer. It is simply

```
p = [pp1(I) pp2(I) pp3(I)]
```

If anyone has a better solution I would appreciate any comments.